# SQL Server FILESTREAM Won't Enable access for I/O

Tags: sql-server-2012, filestream

I have a SQL Server 2012 64 bit version running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit version. I wanted to enable the FILESTREAM feature.

In the FILESTREAM tab of the properties of SQL Server in config manager, I can enable the option for Transact-SQL access but when I try to enable the option for file I/O access, I get the following error message:
There was an unknown error applying the FILESTREAM settings. Check the parameters are valid. (0x80070001)

Then on the bottom of the page there is a message that says:
A previous FILESTREAM configuration attempt was incomplete. FILESTREAM may be in an inconsistent state until re-configured.

What exactly does this mean? How can I re-configure it?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you had a previous FILESTREAM setting that produced some kind of error?

Comment: No. It gave me the error the first time I tried and then the next time I tried, that error message was there.

Answer (score 0):

I catched this error on one of my servers in my company. I read the Event Viewer of the server and I found that a Cumulative of sql server automaticaly ran on the server but the setup didn't run completery. I found the CU and downloaded it again and ran the patch. then I can Enable FileStaram Item on the Sql Server Engine.